# Как применить атрибут 'colspan' не зная точного количества ячеек?

Tags: html

есть у меня таблица, и в ней будет через каждые 5 строк с данными - одна строка которая будет по длине на всю таблицу (строка с одной длинной ячейкой) Но проблема в том, что количество ячеек может быть разное, есть фильтр который может одни столбцы скрывать, другие показывать, и недьзя просто поставить аттрибут с конкретным числом.

```css
.hidden {
  /*
  display:none;
  ?*/
}
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>example1</td>
      <td>example2</td>
      <td>example3</td>
      <td class="hidden">example4</td>
      <td>example5</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>info_1</td>
      <td>info_2</td>
      <td>info_3</td>
      <td class="hidden">info_4</td>
      <td>info_5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!-- //надо чтоб во эта была всегда на всю длину -->
      <td colspan="5">Information about next string</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>info_1</td>
      <td>info_2</td>
      <td>info_3</td>
      <td class="hidden">info_4</td>
      <td>info_5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: `class="hidden"` - ?

Comment: @Igor hidden - скрытая ячейка, пользователь может выбирать какие отображать а какие нет, это для примера, скрытой может быть любая, и даже несколько

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось очень просто.... *colspan="100%"* и ячейка на всю длину

Comment: Это решение не будет работать, если в таблице будет 101 столбец, знак процента в вашем случае просто игнорируется

Comment: а... ну спасибо, там и так нет больше 50